# Does **accomplish** have an object in the following sentence?

Tags: objects, indirect-objects

Does **accomplish** have an object in the following sentence?

> The stability of this growth over extended
>   periods, during which policies and circumstances varied, is quite remarkable
>   and again raises questions regarding what economic policies are able
>   to ***accomplish***.

I think it is ***the stability of this growth*** but I am not sure. I am not sure it has an object at all.

Comment: It is the _economic policies_ which can _do_ the _accomplishing_ here. _What_ can be the object of **to accomplish....** ?

Comment: "What" is object of "accomplish". "What economic policies are able to accomplish" is a subordinate interrogative clause. The meaning of the sentence is "... raises questions regarding the answer to the question 'What are economic policies able to accomplish?"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest **what** is the object of to accomplish

> what economic policies are able to accomplish
>
> economic policies are able to accomplish what?

Comment: @djna You mean that economic policy cannot do anything or they haven't anything to do with this success?

Comment: **I** was saying only that **what** is the object. The author is arguing that as growth was seemingly consistent through a range of different policies this may suggest that, as you say, that the policies did not influence the success.

Comment: @comi - That is a question about _comprehension._ You're asking djna to explain the entire sentence not in terms of its structure, but in terms of the context of an entire book by Shahid Yusuf. That's off-topic here. We haven't read _Development Economics through the Decades: A Critical Look at Thirty Years of the World Development Report._

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I am really sorry, I know that  I am ....somehow. You know this book is really very difficult for a beginner like me and It is really making me .... Again, I am sorry.

Comment: @comi English is diffiicult, and a scholarly work like this one must be a very heavy slog for a non-native speaker. I sympathize, I reaaly do! But you aren't going to get the depth of help you really need at this site, I think. If you are at university, isn't there a tutor to help you, either with this course or with English in general? You seem quite fluent already, and I don't think it would take long for you to gain the skills you need.

Comment: @comi  The author suggests that we are compelled to ask  "What did the policies accomplish?" That is, since growth was stable while economic policy varied, how can we attribute the growth to the policies? The author does not give an answer in the passage you have given us.

Comment: @P.E.Dant. Thank you for your advice. I have read several books but this one is really different and difficult. I am at university, but at our university there isn't anyone to help me through this book because it is an specialized book.  The author has its own style in writing. I have been learning English for several years but as you put it correctly "English is difficult".

Comment: @StoneyB. Thanks a lot for your helpful reply. I got the point by your help.

Comment: @StoneyB In the vast realm that is *.stackexchange, is there a * where Mr Yusuf's and similar economics-related works are discussed? Maybe comi would benefit more from such a site than from this one, where we can only help with usages &c.